# Attempting to generate links from all products on website using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

The main goal of the script is to generate links for all the products available on the website, the products are segregated based on categories.

The issue I am having is that I can only generate links for one category (infusion), specifically the URL I have saved. The second category or URL, I would like to include is here: https://www.vatainc.com/wound-care.html

Is there a way I can loop through multiple category URLs, that have the same effect of the script I already have?

Here is my code:

```
import time
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.service as service
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

all_product = []

url = "https://www.vatainc.com/infusion.html?limit=all"
service = service.Service('/Users/Jon/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')
service.start()
capabilities = {'chrome.binary': '/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'}
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, capabilities)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
links = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'product-name')]/a")]


 for link in links:
    html = requests.get(link).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    products = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "product-view"})
    print(links)
```

Here is some of the output, there are approximately 52 links from this one URL.

```
['https://www.vatainc.com/infusion/0705-vascular-access-ultrasound-phantom-1616.html', 'https://www.vatainc.com/infusion/0751-simulated-ultrasound-blood.html', 'https://www.vatainc.com/infusion/body-skin-shell-0242.html', 'https://www.vatainc.com/infusion/2366-advanced-four-vein-venipuncture-training-aidtm-dermalike-iitm-latex-free-1533.html',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just loop through the 2 urls. But if you were looking for a way to pull those first, and then loop through, this works:

```
import time
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.service as service
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


root_url = 'https://www.vatainc.com/'
service = service.Service('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
service.start()
capabilities = {'chrome.binary': '/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'}
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, capabilities)
driver.get(root_url)
time.sleep(2)

# Grab the urls, but only keep the ones of interest
urls = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ol[contains(@class, 'nav-primary')]/li/a")]
urls = [ x for x in urls if 'html' in x ] 

# It produces duplicates, so drop those and include ?limit=all to query all products
urls_list = pd.Series(urls).drop_duplicates().tolist()
urls_list = [ x +'?limit=all' for x in urls_list]

driver.close()


all_product = []

# loop through those urls and the links to generate a final product list
for url in urls_list:

    print ('Url: '+url)
    driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, capabilities)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    links = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'product-name')]/a")]


    for link in links:
        html = requests.get(link).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        products = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "product-view"})
        all_product.append(link)
        print(link)

    driver.close()
```

produces list of 303 links

Answer (score 0):

Just using a simple for loop to enumerate through the two URLS:

```
import time
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.service as service
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

all_product = []

urls = ["website", "website2"]
service = service.Service('/Users/Jonathan/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')
service.start()
capabilities = {'chrome.binary': '/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'}
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, capabilities)
for index, url in enumerate(urls):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    links = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'product-name')]/a")]
    


for link in links:
    html = requests.get(link).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    products = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "product-view"})
    print(links)
```